# How to use javascript to select a row of radio buttons when a checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need to do is check to see if the checkbox is checked, and if so, select all the radio buttons located within the same  element?

I've set up the  elements with id's, b/c that is the "physical" grouping of the elements that will be affecting each other.

I'm trying to do something like this onchange('some_row_id'):

```
function select_row(row_id) {
  // Get 1st td element (where checkbox is located) and assign its
  // checked value to variable "checked"
  var checked = document.getElementById(row_id).td[0].input.checked;

  if(checked) {
    var children = document.getElementById(row_id).childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i< children.length; i++) {
      if(children.td.type == radio) {
        children.td.radio = checked;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that javascript is almost 200% wrong, but I can't figure out how to properly select only td children (or prefereably, only input grandchildren) of a tr element and check them.

Here's the basic form structure in actual working html:

```
<form name="form2" action="testfile4.php" method="get">
<table border="1"><thead>
    <tr><th>Select entire row</th><th>item_code</th><th>description</th><th>page</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="534">
        <td ><input type="checkbox" onchange="select_row(534);"></td>       <td>15038         <input type="radio" name="15819-038|item_code" value="534" /></td>
        <td>For 1st item,  alternate 1
        <input type="radio" name="15819-038|description" value="534" /></td>
        <td>5
          <input type="radio" name="15819-038|page" value="534" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr id="535">
        <td ><input type="checkbox" onchange="select_row(535);"></td>       <td>15038         <input type="radio" name="15819-038|item_code" value="535" /></td>
        <td>For 1st item, alternate 2         <input type="radio" name="15819-038|description" value="535" /></td>
        <td>5
          <input type="radio" name="15819-038|page" value="535" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

EDIT:
I'm willing to accept jquery solutions. Thank you.

EDIT 2:
Thanks to  nnnnnn. I used your JS and added this to have the uncheck behavior I wanted. If you want you can update your answer with it and I'll remove it from here:

```
 else if (!row.cells[0].childNodes[0].checked) {
        inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].type === "radio") {
                inputs[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is way simpler with jQuery. Just sayin'.

Comment: I'm fine with using jQuery. Let me know if you have a way to do it with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's one way to do it:

```
function select_row(row_id) {
   // get a reference to the row based on the id passed in
   var row = document.getElementById(row_id),
       inputs;

   // .cells[0] gives the row's first td element,
   // then .childNodes[0] gives that td's first child element which
   // will be the checkbox
   if (row.cells[0].childNodes[0].checked) {
      // getElementsByTagName gives all descendent elements with the matching
      // tag, not just direct children, so get all the inputs for the current
      // row and loop through them looking for the radios
      inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
         if (inputs[i].type==="radio")
             inputs[i].checked = true;
      }
   }
}
```

And change your checkbox to use `onclick=...` instead of `onchange=...`.

Note that using checkboxes to select a row doesn't really make sense because after selecting one, if you click another row's checkbox the first row's checkbox is still checked. You might be better off with a button or `<a>` element for this purpose.

Note also that instead of passing the row ID to the function and then getting a reference to that row using the ID, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="select_row(534)">

function select_row(row_id) {
   var row = document.getElementById(row_id);
   // etc
```

You can directly pass a reference to the checkbox that was clicked and use that instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="select_row(this);">

function select_row(cb) {
   var row = cb.parentNode.parentNode;
   if (cb.checked) {
      // etc
```

However in my full solution above I stuck with passing the ID like you did in case you are calling the function from somewhere other than just the click event.

There were several things wrong with your code as posted:

- You can't get children of a particular element just by refering to their type, e.g., `getElementById(row_id).td[0].input` doesn't work. To get the first td you can use a row's `cells` collection and say `.cells[0]` (like in my code).
- Your for loop doesn't use the `i` variable within the loop to select the individual items. You should've said `children[i]` within the loop.
- Your if statement: `if(children.td.type = radio) {` is doing an assignment (single = sign) instead of a comparison (double == or triple === equals sign), and should be comparing to the string `"radio"` (with quotes).

Comment: Perhaps I should just have "check all" and "uncheck all" links with onclick attributes.

Comment: Thanks, nnnnnn, this works brilliantly. Now I need to figure out the solution to the checkbox problem. I'll ask another question for that.

Comment: Well as in my updated answer I'd suggest a button or hyperlink rather than a checkbox. Does it make sense for the user to select the column 2 radio of the first row at the same time as the column 3 radio of the second row? What would "uncheck all" do?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense because the user will pick and choose which values from each row are "good". That's the whole reason for the radios. The checkbox is to speed things up when they determine that an entire row, or most of it, is "good" (and the other is "bad"). I thought about a button or hyperlink. But 1 checkbox replaces 2 hyperlinks ("check all" and "uncheck all"). The button would have indeterminate behavior if only some radios were selected.  I.e. i can click the checkbox and select all radios in that row, then change one of those to the other option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want jquery solution then here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#your_checkbpx_id").click(function() {
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //select all your radio
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("tr[id='"+id+"'] > input[type='radio']").each(function() {
           //make it checked
           $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        });
     }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    Loops through all input elements finding all checkboxs. 
    Testing if the current checkbox obj is equal to the selected checkbox object.
    If equal: Set the radio button to the current state of the checkbox.
    Not equal: Set its children radio buttons checked property false 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    */
    function setCheckboxs(checkBox) {
        var parent, i;
        var checkBoxs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < checkBoxs.length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxs[i].getAttribute("type") === "checkbox") {
                parent = checkBoxs[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                if (checkBox === checkBoxs[i]) {
                    toggleRadios(parent.childNodes, checkBoxs[i].checked);
                } else {
                    checkBoxs[i].checked = false;
                    toggleRadios(parent.childNodes, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    Loops through all its children nodes finding a node's attribute equal to radio
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    */        
    function toggleRadios(radios, isChecked) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
                toggleRadios(radios[i].childNodes, isChecked);
            }
            if (radios[i].nodeName === "INPUT") {
                if (radios[i].getAttribute("type") === "radio") {
                    radios[i].checked = isChecked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Select entire row
            </th>
            <th>
                item_code
            </th>
            <th>
                page
            </th>
            <th>
                usd_dn
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="534" class="15838">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxs(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                15838<input type="radio" name="15838|item_code" value="534" />
            </td>
            <td>
                284<input type="radio" name="15838|page" value="534" />
            </td>
            <td>
                $73.00<input type="radio" name="15838|usd_dn" value="534" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="535" class="15838">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxs(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                15838
                <input type="radio" name="15838|item_code" value="535" />
            </td>
            <td>
                299
                <input type="radio" name="15838|page" value="535" />
            </td>
            <td>
                $73.00<input type="radio" name="15838|usd_dn" value="535" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="565">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxs(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                1611
                <input type="radio" name="1611|item_code" value="565" />
            </td>
            <td>
                66<input type="radio" name="1611|page" value="565" />
            </td>
            <td>
                $3,350.00
                <input type="radio" name="1611|usd_dn" value="565" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="566">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxs(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                1611
                <input type="radio" name="1611|item_code" value="566" />
            </td>
            <td>
                66<input type="radio" name="1611|page" value="566" />
            </td>
            <td>
                $3,225.00
                <input type="radio" name="1611|usd_dn" value="566" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```